# Как избежать дублирование дат в Django

Tags: html, django

Как избежать дублирование дат(el.date), т.е. сгруппировать новости по датам, чтобы было отображение, пример, 09.06 и после список новостей с этой датой, далее 08.06 и т.д? Если делать как указано ниже, то для каждого элемента выводится дата.

```
          {% for el in content %}
                <p class="lead">{{el.date}}</p>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <p class="lead"><a href="{{el.url}}" style="color: black;">{{el.title}}</a></p>
                    <p class="mb-0">{{el.content|linebreaksbr}} </p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте тег regroup для перегруппировки по нужному атрибуту. Одного for тут не достаточно, измените структуру таким образом чтобы у вас был for в for-е. Вот пример из документации Django:

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for city in country.list %}
          <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось.

Comment: @Роман если я вам помог, то выбирите, пожалуйста, мой ответ верным (поставьте галочку над моим ответом) - это самая лучшая благодарность :)